# Is a set closed under finite intersections? (about filters)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, filters

In [my research](http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html) I was faced [with the problem](http://portonmath.tiddlyspace.com/) (as a special example and a pattern for more general problems) whether the family $\operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$ of sets is closed regarding finite intersections.

To make the problem accessible for these who have not read [my book](http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html), I will define it in elementary terms:

$\operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$ is a set of binary relations on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by the formula:

$$f \in \operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta) \Leftrightarrow
\forall X \in \mathscr{P} \mathbb{R} : ( (\forall D \in \Delta : X \cap D \neq
\varnothing) \Rightarrow f [X] \in \Delta)$$

where $\Delta$ is the filter of neighborhoods of zero on real line, that is the filter generated by the set $\{(-\epsilon;\epsilon) \,|\, \epsilon\in\mathbb{R}, \epsilon>0 \}$ and $f[X] = \{ y \,|\, \exists x\in X: (x,y) \in f \}$.

Is $\operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$ closed under finite intersections?

Comment: It is enough to prove that for every $f \in \operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$ there is a positive $\varepsilon$ such that $\forall x \in ( - \varepsilon ; \varepsilon) : f[\{x\}] \in \Delta$.

Comment: The above comment is proved in http://portonmath.tiddlyspace.com/#[[Singularities%20funcoids%3A%20special%20cases%20proof%20attempts]]

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld: I added more parentheses to the formula. It seems you misunderstood me

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld: Do you assume that $f$ is a function? $f$ is a binary relation, not necessarily a function

Comment: porton: There's my error. Thank you for your patience. (Also, the question you actually are asking makes a lot more sense now. :))

Comment: Probably I misunderstood the problem, but it seems to be trivial. Suppose that $f_1,f_2 \in \operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$. Then there exist positive $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ such that $f[\{x_1\}]\in\Delta$ for each $x_1\in (-\epsilon_1, \epsilon_1)$ and $f[\{x_2\}]\in\Delta$ for each $x_2\in (-\epsilon_2, \epsilon_2)$. Put $f=f_1\cap f_2$ and $\epsilon=\min\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}$. If $x\in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ then $f[\{x\}]\supset f_1[\{x\}]\cap f_2[\{x\}]\ni\Delta$, because $\Delta$ is a filter. So $f\in\operatorname{GR} (\Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}}\Delta)$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky: It is not proved that there exists positive $\epsilon_1$ such that $f[\{x_1\}]\in\Delta$ for each $x_1\in(-\epsilon_1,\epsilon_1)$.

Comment: @porton Thanks for your answer. Then I do a second try. It seems the following. Put $f_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:|x|\le |y|$ or $y=0\}$ and $f_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:|x|\ge |y|$ or $x=0\}$. Then $f_1, f_2\in\operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$ but $f_1\cap f_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:|x|=|y|$ or $x=0$ or $y=0\}\not\in\operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$. Is this example OK?

Comment: @AlexRavsky: I earlier wrote that your answer is not correct. That my comment was wrong and I deleted it. Really, your counter-example is correct. I suggest you to write it as an answer, so that I could accept it

Comment: @porton OK. So I can write the example from my first comment as an answer?

Comment: @AlexRavsky: No! Your first comment was wrong. You provided a correct counter-example in your second comment. Please make an answer based on your second comment, not first!

Comment: @porton Thanks for the explanation. I wrote the example from my second comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the following. Put $f_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:|x|\le |y|$ or $y=0\}$ and $f_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:|x|\ge |y|$ or $x=0\}$. Then $f_1, f_2\in\operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$ but $f_1\cap f_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:|x|=|y|$ or $x=0$ or $y=0\}\not\in\operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$.

Comment: I am not convinced that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are in $\operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$. Note that $f\in \operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$ iff for every sequence $s_n\to 0$, $f[\{s_n\}]\in\Delta$. But, try $f_2$ on, say, $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld: Due funcoid magic $f_1\in\operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta) \Leftrightarrow f_2\in\operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$ and moreover $\operatorname{GR} ( \Delta \times^{\mathsf{FCD}} \Delta)$ is symmetric, see http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html

Comment: @porton Forget my deleted comment, $0\notin f_1[\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}]$. So, indeed, neither $f_1$ nor $f_2$ is in $GR(\dots)$.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld: $0\in f_1(1/n)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ because $(1/n,0)\in f_1$

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld: You missed $y=0$ in the definition of $f_1$

Comment: @porton I apologize for my silliness yesterday. Of course this is correct. (Alex Ravsky: If you edit your answer, I'll be able to remove my stupid downvote)

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld Never mind. It seems that the notations from specialists in this domain are not easily perceived outside it. For instance, it took me some time to understand the question. After that it was not so hard to find the answer. I edited my answer.